# 'Someone who just came back from a trip' and 'someone who greets or welcomes him' at the airport

Tags: word-request

I have a picture showing someone having some luggage shaking hands with someone else who is greeting him and giving him a welcome back. I want to describe the picture and I wonder what I can call each of them: *a person who just came back from a trip* and *the other who's greeting him at the airport and probably is going to give him a ride back home*.

I'm thinking of *passenger* but that person is not on a trip anymore and I think I can't call him so. Also *arrival* but I feel it's too general.

For the other person greeting him, the first word was a *pick up* that occured to me but I'm not sure it's even right but even if it is it doesn't imply greeting or welcoming and it strongly suggest the person is there to give him the lift.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: You need to indicate the context where you'd use such words.  For example, are you describing this scenario for security personnel, so that you'd be looking for *terminology*, or in a casual conversation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a standard situation like this
[image: here]
<sub>(source: [rackcdn.com](http://d9e1a3e4cf046f17aa52-abd76f89d11702d9e2f53ed0fc943ea2.r90.cf1.rackcdn.com/190/1/large.jpg))</sub>
One person is the **traveller**, and the other is the **driver**, the situation is a **pick up**.
As in, the traveller will tell his secretary "Have the driver pick me up outside Arrivals."

It might also be the case that the one who is travelling is a **visitor**.

In the world of espionage, a **spy** would look for his **contact** or **handler**.

When the traveller is a visitor then **greeters** or **meeters** are often on hand

[image: here]
<sub>(source: [halong-tours.net](http://halong-tours.net/uploads/tours-type/2015_03/airport-pick-up.jpg))</sub>
[image: here]


they are there to make the visitor feel welcomed and help them along in general, not just with transportation.

Or maybe it's just your Mom...

[image: here]



In general, they are called **greeters**

[image: here]

Comment: Can you clarify whether you would refer to "your mom" (or some other generic social or familial acquaintance who is shaking hands with the traveller) as a "greeter?"  I wouldn't, but that may be a regional difference.

Comment: I wasn't classifying "Mom" as a meeter/greeter, I just meant she was "Mom", though the airport authorities would consider *anyone* meeting *someone* as a *meeter/greeter*, so they would consider "your Mom" as a meeter/greeter for you (if you were the traveller), even at PDX they have a "meeter and greeter" area.

Comment: A "meeter and greeter" area? That sounds rather odd to me; I'd prefer a "greeting" area, or just "Arrivals".

Comment: According to the Transportation Research Board's *Airport Passenger Terminal Planning and Design: Guidebook* "[there is a need for domestic meeter/greeter areas](https://books.google.com/books?id=H8GVxyHeuZsC&pg=PA226&lpg=PA226&dq=meeter+greeter+airport+areas&source=bl&ots=aaTbQuPt5b&sig=PCX6gWPrmpBbXMVVMdlIB0DHjaA&hl=en&sa=X&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwjWmtiLiePMAhWI5IMKHWLrDGAQ6AEIKjAC#v=onepage&q=meeter%20greeter%20airport%20areas&f=false)"